# Organizing history.js into HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: jquery, html

I read [HTML5 Boilerplate plugins.js answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572659/html5-boilerplate-plugins-js) which says to concatenate the js plugins needed using a makefile/script. Though on the [Boilerplate site](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#Build-Script) it says it will already do this if you use the build script:

> Combines and minifies javascript (via yui compressor)

So in terms of a plugin such as [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/#readme), do I just follow balupton's installation instructions or use the uncompressed set then concatenate manually or can I just throw the uncompressed set into plugins.js and then let the build take care of it ?

I guess in the end each person has their own style, I was just wondering whether anyone used history.js with the Boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to use the uncompressed version of the plugin and let the build take care of compressing it.  This way you have the uncompressed version for easier debugging in the dev build but still have the minified version in the production build.